# I am using Laravel 7 and I keep getting transaction errors daily, but only once or twice a day

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7, mysql-8.0

Error message: There is already an active transaction

I keep seeing that error with laravel 7 and it makes no sense to me. It's not like the code is run twice, I triple checked to make sure we couldn't send the insert command more than once and even by sending it twice through postman, there is no issue.

I also could not find anything other than the primary key being unique, which is an auto-generated auto-increment key. Trying to add the same thing twice through the interface gives a duplicate error to the user, so that can't be it either.

It is only referencing two IDs from the users table and the organization tables, both of which are proper foreign keys.

I can even make the same entry twice using an insert directly in mysql with no issue and the only difference is my primary id is properly incremented.

The code causing the issue:

```
$result = DB::transaction(function () use ($insertArray) {
    return DB::table('tableName')->insertGetId($insertArray);
}, 5);
```

Now the funny thing is that even when this error occurs, the data is in the database when I check AND worst of all, it only happens rarely. 99.9% of the time, there is no error thrown. At this point I think it's a mysql issue more than a laravel issue, since it's very sporadic, but I can't reproduce it at will so it's hard to know what exactly the issue could be.

Laravel Framework 7.30.6

Server version: 8.0.27 MySQL Community Server - GPL

I am looking for other ideas as to what seems to be causing the issues or if I'm lucky, the solution for this.

Comment: Ok thanks: 
In the title I assumed it was a deadlock error, but it could be something else. 
I also added the exact error message from the error email we get right at the beginning.

Comment: What makes you sure it's not PHP extension's bug; Laravel simply uses the API which PHP extensions provide - try updating PHP's database related extensions.